# Goldbach-type problem: the valuation of irreducible elements of a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}_{> 0}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, prime-numbers, valuation-theory, goldbach-type-problems

Let $\phi : \mathbb{Q}_{>0} \to \mathbb{Z}$ be the group morphism defined by $\phi(p) = p$ for $p$ a prime number.
   It follows that $\phi(\prod_i p_i^{n_i}) = \sum_i n_i p_i$, with $p_i$ a prime number and $n_i \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Let $v: \mathbb{Q}_{>0} \to \mathbb{N}$ be the map defined by $v(\prod_i p_i^{n_i}) = \sum_i \vert n_i \vert$ (with $i \neq j \Rightarrow p_i \neq p_j$).
The map $v$ is not a really a [valuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(algebra)), nevertheless  $v = \sum_p \vert v_p \vert$, with $v_p$ the $p$-adic valuation.

Let $\mathcal{K} = \{  r \in \mathbb{Q}_{>0} \  \vert \   r=\prod_i p_i^{n_i}   \text{ and }   \sum_i n_i p_i = 0 \} =  ker (\phi) $, a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$.

**Definition:** An element $r \in \mathcal{K} $ is called **irreducible** if  $r \neq 1$ and if :  $$ r =  \prod_i r_i  \text{ (with } r_i \in \mathcal{K}) \Rightarrow  \exists i \text{ such that }   v(r_i) \ge v(r) $$
**Warning**: The notion of irreducible defined above is **different** with the notion of "irreducible fraction".

**Example**:  Let $(p,p+2)$ be [twin primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_prime), then $r=\frac{2p}{p+2} $ is an irreducible element of $\mathcal{K}$ and  $v(r) = 3$.

> **Question**:  Let  $r \in \mathcal{K} $ be an irreducible element. Is it true that  $v(r) \in \{ 3,4 \}$ ?

**Application**: The group $\mathcal{K}$ is generated by its irreducible elements, so (modulo a positive anwser), it's generated by the elements $v$ with $v(r) \in \{ 3,4 \}$.

**Edit** (14/07/14): It's a **Goldbach-type problem**: two days after having posted my question, I've found a proof using the Goldbach conjecture (see my answer below). So an alternative question could be:
Is it possible to answer my question without using the Goldbach conjecture or is it equivalent to it ?

Comment: Is $8/9$ irreducible?

Comment: **Warning**: The notion of irreducible defined above is **different** with the notion of "irreducible fraction". For example $8/9$ is not irreducible in the sense above because $\frac{2.2.2}{3.3} = \frac{2.11}{13}.\frac{13}{3.3.7}.\frac{2.2.7}{11}$.

Comment: I've posted an answer using the Goldbach's weak conjecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, here is a proof by induction on an integer $n$, assuming the [**Goldbach conjecture**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_conjecture), or alternatively, just using the *[Goldbach's weak conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_weak_conjecture)* (see at the end), *proved* in 2013, by [Harald Helfgott](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harald_Helfgott).

Note that an element $a \in \mathcal{K}$, $a \neq 1$, is given by an integer $n$ and two different prime partitions of $n$, $p_1 + \dots + p_r  = q_1 + \dots + q_s = n$, with $p_1 \le \dots \le p_r$, $q_1 \le \dots \le q_s$, and  $p_i$,$q_j$ prime numbers,
such that $a= \frac{p_1  \dots  p_r}{q_1  \dots  q_s}$.

**Base case**: The smallest $n$ having two different prime partitions is $n_0=6=2+2+2=3+3$.
But $a=\frac{2.2.2}{3.3} = \frac{2.11}{13}.\frac{13}{3.3.7}.\frac{2.2.7}{11}$, so it's true for $n_0 = 6$.

**Inductive step**: Now, suppose it's true up to $n$, we will prove it's also true for $n+1$.
Let two different prime partitions of $(n+1)$,  $p_1 + \dots + p_r  = q_1 + \dots + q_s = n+1$, and $a= \frac{p_1  \dots  p_r}{q_1  \dots  q_s}$ such that $v(a) = r+s \ge 5$. We will show that $a$ is not an  irreducible element.
Without loose of generality, we can suppose that $\forall i, j$ , $p_i \neq q_j $.

**Case 1**: If $p_r$ and $q_s$ are odd, for example $p_r > q_s$, then $p_r = q_s + 2k$ and $s>1$.
Now $a =  \frac{2^k . p_1  \dots  p_{r-1}}{q_1  \dots  q_{s-1}}.\frac{ p_{r}}{2^k.q_{s}}$.
**Case 1.1**: If $r>1$ or $k \le 2$, then we can apply the induction.
**Case 1.2**: If $r=1$ and $k > 2$, then  $s \ge 4$, because $v(a) \ge 5$.
By the **Goldbach's conjecture**, $2k = p+q$ with $p$, $q$ odd prime numbers, then $a =  \frac{2^k}{q_1  \dots  q_{s-1}}. \frac{ p.q}{2^k}. \frac{ p_{1}}{p.q.q_{s}}$, and we can apply the induction.

**Case 2**: If $p_r$ or $q_s = 2$, for example $p_r=2$.
Then $p_1= \dots = p_r = 2$ (because $p_1 \le \dots \le p_r$), 
and $\forall j$ , $q_j \neq 2$
**Case 2.1**: If $s > 2$, then $s \ge 4$. Now, $q_1 + q_2 = 2k < 2r$ and
$a= \frac{2^r}{q_1  \dots  q_s}=  \frac{2^k}{q_1 . q_2} . \frac{2^{r-k}}{q_3  \dots  q_s}$, so we can apply the induction.
**Case 2.2**: If $s = 2$  and $q_2 \neq 3$,  then  $q_2 = 2k+ 3$ with $k \ge 1$ and
$a= \frac{2^{r-k}}{3.q_1}. \frac{2^k.3}{q_2}$, so we can apply the induction.
**Case 2.3**:  If $s = 2$  and $q_2 = 3$, then  $q_1 = 3$ and $n=6= n_0$, it's the base case.

---

**Edit**: We can also just using the **[Goldbach's weak conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%27s_weak_conjecture)**:

*Case 1.2*: if $r=1$.
By Goldbach's weak conjecture, $p_1 = d_1+d_2+d_3$ with $(d_i)$ odd prime numbers,
then $a = \frac{p}{d_1.d_2.d_3}.b$ with $b = \frac{d_1.d_2.d_3}{q_1 \dots q_s}$.    If $\forall i, j$, $d_i \neq q_j$, then we can apply the case 1.1 to $b$,   else we can simplify the fraction and apply the induction.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Hardy-Littlewood conjecture for pairs of primes, we have the bound $v(r) \leq 5$. If $v(r) \geq 6$, we can split the prime factors of $r$ into two piles, each of size at least $3$, such that the signed sum of the primed factors in each pile is even. Take that even number and find two primes whose difference is that number. Add those primes appropriately to the numerator and denominator of both piles. They're in $\mathcal K$, and smaller. So it's not irreducible.

Comment: Do you have an example with $v(r)=5$ ?

Comment: Perhaps the purpose of the Hardy-Littlewood conjecture is for the existence of "two prime numbers whose difference is" a given even number, isn't it ?

Comment: No, I don't have an example for 5.  Yes, that is the purpose. e.g. if the even number is 2, I need twin primes.

Comment: I've posted an answer for the bound $v(r) \le 4$,  using the Goldbach conjecture.